# Is a reason I can't add a ManyToManyField?

Tags: python, django, django-models

So I'm building a Django application,
and these are a few models I have:

```
class MagicType(models.Model):

     name = models.CharField(max_length=155)
     parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True)

class Spell(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, db_index=True)
    magic_words = models.CharField(max_length=250, db_index=True)
    magic_types = models.ManyToManyField(MagicType)
```

When syncing the models I'm getting this error:

```
AttributeError: 'ManyToManyField' object has no attribute '_get_m2m_column_name'
```

Is there a reason this is happening? How can I fix this?

Help would be very much appreciated.

---

**EDIT:**

I'm using django-evolution http://code.google.com/p/django-evolution/

Comment: On a clean install of a Django 1.1 project, the code you've posted works perfectly.

Comment: What could be the cause of this then? I'm using SVN version.

Comment: Do you have any kind of schema migration installed?

Comment: I think you need to investigate @Jarret's observation more closely. Try installing a clean 1.1.1 in a new directory and see if this suddenly works. Whether it works or not it gives you a direction to explore.

Comment: Stone I have django-evolution!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you use django-extensions , this will give you a commnad `sqldiiff` that works better than evolution, because there is a problem creating the intermediate table between MagicType and MagicType.

I suggest you run the command `sqlall yourapp` and execute directly the sql code of the creation of the new intermediate table. Evolution doesn't it for you :(

Comment: Thanks I will look into it, I have extensions already installed, but I have never used that feature. Time to try it out!

Answer (score 3):

Is MagicType declared in the same models file (and before) Spell?

Does `magic_types = models.ManyToManyField('MagicType')`  work (with 'MagicType' quoted)?